# Recode multiple columns to numbers increasingly in R

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I have 50 columns of names, but here I have presented only 4 columns for convenience.

```
Name1       Name2         Name3      Name4
Rose,Ali    Van,Hall      Ghol,Dam   Murr,kate
Camp,Laura  Ka,Klo        Dan,Dan    Ali,Hoss
Rose,Ali    Van,Hall      Ghol,Dam   Kol,Kan
Murr,Kate   Ismal, Ismal  Sian,Rozi  Nas,Ami
Ghol,Dam    Ka,Klo        Rose,Ali   Nor,Ko
Murr,Kate   Ismal, Ismal  Dan,Dan    Nas,Ami
```

I want to assign numbers to each person based on the columns, a sequence of numbers.

For example, in Name 1, we get the numbers from 1-4. The repeated names will get the same numbers.

In Name 2, it should be started from 5 and so on. This will give me the following table:

```
Assign1 Assian2 Assian3 Assian4
      1       5       8      12
      2       6       9      13
      1       5       8      14
      3       7      10      15
      4       6      11      17
      3       7       9      15
```

I would like to have it without a loop, i.e.,`sapply`,i.e., `sapply(dat, function(x) match(x, unique(x)))`.

Using `dplyr` or `tidyverse` would be great.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A `tidyverse` solution with `purrr::accumulate()`:

```r
library(tidyverse)

df %>%
  mutate(as_tibble(
    accumulate(across(Name1:Name4, ~ match(.x, unique(.x))), ~ .y + max(.x))
  ))

#   Name1 Name2 Name3 Name4
# 1     1     5     8    12
# 2     2     6     9    13
# 3     1     5     8    14
# 4     3     7    10    15
# 5     4     6    11    16
# 6     3     7     9    15
```

Comment: Very nice. This answer gets my vote.

Comment: This  a great solution, Upvoted

Answer (score 5):

Because the values in each column depend on the values in the previous column, the calculations have to be done sequentially. This is probably most succinctly achieved by a loop. Remember that `lapply` and `sapply` are simply loops-in-disguise, and won't be quicker than an explicit loop.

Note that your expected output has a mistake in it (there is a number 17 which should be 16)

```r
output <- setNames(df, paste0('Assign', seq_along(df)))
                   
for(i in seq_along(output)) {
  output[[i]] <- match(output[[i]], unique(output[[i]]))
  if(i > 1) output[[i]] <- output[[i]] + max(output[[i - 1]])
}

output
#>    Assign1  Assign2  Assign3  Assign4
#> 1        1        5        8       12
#> 2        2        6        9       13
#> 3        1        5        8       14
#> 4        3        7       10       15
#> 5        4        6       11       16
#> 6        3        7        9       15
```

---

**Edit**

If you really want it without an explicit loop, you can do:

```r
res <- sapply(seq_along(df), \(i) match(df[[i]], unique(df[[i]]))) 
res + t(replicate(nrow(df), head(c(0, cumsum(apply(res, 2, max))), -1))) |>
  as.data.frame() |>
  setNames(paste0('Assign', seq_along(df)))
#>   Assign1 Assign2 Assign3 Assign4
#> 1       1       5       8      12
#> 2       2       6       9      13
#> 3       1       5       8      14
#> 4       3       7      10      15
#> 5       4       6      11      16
#> 6       3       7       9      15
```

<sup>Created on 2023-01-13 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

---

**Data taken from question in reproducible format**

```r
df <- structure(list(Name1 = c("Rose,Ali", "Camp,Laura", "Rose,Ali", 
"Murr,Kate", "Ghol,Dam", "Murr,Kate"), Name2 = c("Van,Hall", 
"Ka,Klo", "Van,Hall", "Ismal, Ismal", "Ka,Klo", "Ismal, Ismal"
), Name3 = c("Ghol,Dam", "Dan,Dan", "Ghol,Dam", "Sian,Rozi", 
"Rose,Ali", "Dan,Dan"), Name4 = c("Murr,kate", "Ali,Hoss", "Kol,Kan", 
"Nas,Ami", "Nor,Ko", "Nas,Ami")), row.names = c(NA, -6L), 
class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Thank you, Allan, I am  not interested in the loop, sorry.

Comment: OK @user330 - I've added a non-loop alternative. To my eye it is more complex and no more efficient than the loop, but it does what you ask in the question.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a `tidyverse` approach:

First `paste` the column name after each of the strings in all your columns, for sorting purpose later. Then `pivot` it into a two-column df so that we can assign ID to them by `match`. Finally `pivot` it back to a wide format and unnest the list columns.

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>% 
  mutate(across(everything(), ~ paste0(.x, "_", cur_column()))) %>% 
  pivot_longer(everything(), names_to = "ab", values_to = "a") %>% 
  arrange(ab) %>% 
  mutate(b = match(a, unique(a)), .keep = "unused") %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = "ab", values_from = "b") %>% 
  unnest(everything())

# A tibble: 6 × 4
  Name1 Name2 Name3 Name4
  <int> <int> <int> <int>
1     1     5     8    12
2     2     6     9    13
3     1     5     8    14
4     3     7    10    15
5     4     6    11    16
6     3     7     9    15
```

#### Data

Taken from @Allan Cameron.

```
df <- structure(list(Name1 = c("Rose,Ali", "Camp,Laura", "Rose,Ali", 
"Murr,Kate", "Ghol,Dam", "Murr,Kate"), Name2 = c("Van,Hall", 
"Ka,Klo", "Van,Hall", "Ismal, Ismal", "Ka,Klo", "Ismal, Ismal"
), Name3 = c("Ghol,Dam", "Dan,Dan", "Ghol,Dam", "Sian,Rozi", 
"Rose,Ali", "Dan,Dan"), Name4 = c("Murr,kate", "Ali,Hoss", "Kol,Kan", 
"Nas,Ami", "Nor,Ko", "Nas,Ami")), row.names = c(NA, -6L), 
class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 1):

**Update: The approach below is not ideal because ID's are not unique. Sorry.**

Using a lookup table with `tidyverse`:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

lookup <-
  df |> 
  pivot_longer(everything()) |>
  distinct() |>
  arrange(name) |>
  transmute(name = value, value = row_number()) |>
  deframe()

df |>
  mutate(across(everything(), ~ recode(., !!!lookup)))
```

Output:

```r
  Name1 Name2 Name3 Name4
1     1     5     4    12
2     2     6     9    13
3     1     5     4    14
4     3     7    10    15
5     4     6     1    16
6     3     7     9    15
```

Data from @Allan Cameron, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

with base R, you can try the code below

```
list2DF(Map(
    `+`,
    lst <- lapply(df, \(x) match(x, unique(x))), 
    c(0, cumsum(sapply(lst, max))[-length(lst)])
))
```

which gives

```
  Name1 Name2 Name3 Name4
1     1     5     8    12
2     2     6     9    13
3     1     5     8    14
4     3     7    10    15
5     4     6    11    16
6     3     7     9    15
```